# USING MULTIPLE DIMENSION ID INTO FACT TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor

INSERT INTO DW_FACT_TABLE( factid, sessionid, tempid)
SELECT DW_FACT_TABLE_SEQ.nextval, c.SESSIONID, t.TEMPID
FROM  DW_SESSION c, dw_temp t;

I am using my University server. I cannot change the space quota and I have dropped a lot of tables that I do not use. I am still getting this error. Any alternative way of using all dimensions ID and putting it into the fact table by using cursor. thank you in advance.
As stated, I am trying to put all dimensions using their ID in the FACT table. I have successfully tried to do SESSION, but adding others using INNER JOIN and CROSS JOIN and CURSOR have not worked. CROSS JOIN gives me 64,000 records that are duplicate of each. 
SESSION has 357 records and TEMP has 182 records.

Comment: Please use modern JOIN syntax, available since SQL-92, that is 28 years ago.

Comment: Do you really want to `CROSS JOIN` four tables? If they each have only 10 rows in them then you are going to get 10,000 rows (10 x 10 x 10 x 10). I'm guessing that this isn't what you want but you haven't given us a [MRE] with any definitions of your tables so I'm not sure we can help you much unless you give us more information on your tables and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a cursor, and you don't even need PL/SQL; you can just use:

```sql
INSERT INTO DW_FACT_TABLE( fact_id, sessionid )
SELECT DW_FACT_TABLE_SEQ.nextval,
       c.SESSIONID
FROM   DW_SESSION s
       CROSS JOIN DW_TEMP a
       CROSS JOIN DW_REFERENCES b
       CROSS JOIN DW_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS c;
```

And you probably don't want to use `CROSS JOIN` (and that is probably what is causing your issues as you are generating too many rows) but without more detail on your table structure and the foreign key references we can't suggest how to improve it.

Something like:

```sql
INSERT INTO DW_FACT_TABLE( fact_id, sessionid )
SELECT DW_FACT_TABLE_SEQ.nextval,
       c.SESSIONID
FROM   DW_SESSION s
       INNER JOIN DW_TEMP t
       ON ( s.fk_to_dw_temp_id = t.id )
       INNER JOIN DW_REFERENCES r
       ON ( t.fk_to_dw_references_id = r.id )
       INNER JOIN DW_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS e
       ON ( r.fk_to_dw_employee_id = e.id );
```

Comment: @anyrandomacc That's almost certainly going to fail as `SELECT *` does not match up with `fact_id, sessionid` columns that are expected.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a constructive statement; what does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: That is not an `INNER JOIN` as you have no correlation between the two tables; it is a `CROSS JOIN`. Use the ANSI join syntx (rather than the legacy comma join) and specify the columns that the two tables are related by. As I said in my answer, we can't help you with this because you have not [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60765050/edit) to provide a [MRE] which describes your table structures and what output you expect and if you don't tell us anything then we don't have any way of knowing what is correct/wanted.